# Error where my login validation isnt validating and breaks if the email that is entered doesnt exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

Hey I'm trying to make a billing service in java/spring boot, but am getting stuck in my login validation.

Here is my login and registration form

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>BillEm</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <form:form action="/register" method="post" modelAttribute="newStore">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Store Name</label>
                        <form:input path="storeName" class="form-control" />
                        <form:errors path="storeName" class="text-danger" />`enter code here`
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Location</label>
                        <form:input path="location" class="form-control" />
                        <form:errors path="location" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <form:input path="email" class="form-control" />
                        <form:errors path="email" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <form:input path="password" class="form-control" />
                        <form:errors path="password" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <form:input path="confirm" class="form-control" />
                        <form:errors path="confirm" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Register Store" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </form:form>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form:form action="/login" method="post" modelAttribute="newStore">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <form:input path="email" class="form-control" />
                        <form:errors path="email" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <form:input path="password" class="form-control" />
                        <form:errors path="password" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login Store" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </form:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my login method which should check if the email exists in my db or if the password matches the one in the DB.

```
public Store loginStore(LoginStore loginStore, BindingResult result) {
    Store store = getByEmail(loginStore.getEmail());
    if (store == null) {
        result.rejectValue("email", "Invalid Credentials");
        return null;
    }
    if(!BCrypt.checkpw(loginStore.getPassword(), store.getPassword())) {
        result.rejectValue("email", "Invalid Credentials");
        return null;
    }
    if (result.hasErrors()){
        return null;
    }
    return store;
}
```

Here is my post mapping which uses the method

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newLogin") LoginStore newLogin, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpSession session) {

    //creates new store model and checks if the email exists or if the password matches the email

    Store storeLoggingIn = storeServ.loginStore(newLogin, result);
    
    //checks for errors
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("newStore", new Store());
        return "Main/LogAndReg.jsp";
    }
    //stores the data into the stores session
    session.setAttribute("store_id", storeLoggingIn.getId());
    return "redirect:/takeOrder";
}
```

This is the error I keep getting which doesn't make sense to me because I'm trying to check for this error. But its skipping that one and going to the next validation.

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot invoke "com.david.billEm.models.Store.getPassword()" because "store" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.david.billEm.models.Store.getPassword()" because "store" is null

Ive tried making it to a store === null but the ide says thats its a syntax error.

Update: I've got it to not show me the error by returning null after the result.rejectValue(etc) but now the validation message isnt popping up.